# Building all of Boost in a few minutes

Tags: c++, boost

Can anyone explain why following these instructions:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install

... it takes my decent machine 5 hours to build all of Boost, while [some folks](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/issues/475#issuecomment-154384120) report doing the same in only 3 *minutes* ?

Is there another way to build Boost than the one mentioned above that indeed goes pretty quickly (compared to several hours, at any rate).

I am using the Clang compiler on Darwin (Mac) option. Not sure how relevant it is but I have 16 GB RAM and a recent SSD. The clock is 2.3 Ghz.

Edit: I'm happy to report, based on the comments and answers, that using the `./b2 -j4 -d0` options, I got my compilation time down to 13 minutes. Also the `-jN` option is not listed in the set of available options with the default `--help`, you must instead call `--help-options` to see these additional more "advanced" techniques.

Comment: which compiler and platform?

Comment: @hellofunk -- You mentioned in the link that you have a quad core, 3 year old macbook. You should be able to reduce that 5 hours to a bit over half an hour by using `make -j8`; see iSanych's answer.

Comment: Does `-d0` really affect the Boost build speed?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just ran a few tests with a few different build configs.

Hardware: 2012 MacBook Pro (2.3Ghz Ivy Bridge i7 [i7-3615QM]), factory SSD and 16GB of ram.

Software: Mac OS X 10.11.1 with Xcode 7 (Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 clang-700.1.76). Fresh copy of Boost 1.59.0 from the website.

I tested the following build commands:

Default Build:

`./bootstrap.sh && ./b2 -j N`

Build forcing the linking of libc++

`./bootstrap.sh && ./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++" -j N`

For each I tried three different values for N: 1 (single thread), 4 (matching physical cores), and 8 (matching hyperthreaded cores).

Default linking:

- With 8 the build time was 6:45 minutes
- With 4 the build time was 7:22 minutes
- With 1 the build time was 22:58 minutes

Linking libc++:

- With 8 the build time was 4:35 minutes
- With 4 the build time was 5:45 minutes
- With 1 the build time was 17:15 minutes

Conclusion: Boost shouldn't have to take all day to build on a multi-core system with an SSD even if it isn't brand new. Building with the default (singled thread) does take way longer than a parallel build. The Boost build with clang on OS X does benefit slightly from hyperthreading. Linking with libc++ seems a bit faster as well.

Comment: Many thanks for the help on this. Your 1 core build may very well take quite a while, I think, if it is anything like mine.

Comment: Are you also getting those hundreds of thousands of build log outputs with the Boost `./b2` ?

Comment: Building with clang produces a lot of repeated compiler warnings that Linux/gcc builds don't. I'll grab an exact count when this build is done, but generally, yes. The configs above produce a lot of output.

Comment: maybe all that logging output is slowing things down for me

Comment: final count for the full build with clang, as described above, was 318116 lines of output. Final build time on that hardware for a single thread was ~17 minutes. Not great, but not 5 hours either. There is probably something else going on with your machine.

Comment: Mine would have fallen under your Default since I didn't pass any options at all, wasn't forcing any linking. I'll look forward to what that test shows in your case as well.

Comment: Is the -j1 build still running?

Comment: I've updated my question the great results from your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: they are all done now. The longest j1 build took 23 minutes on this hardware. Seems like `-j` scaling is almost linear with core count and hyperthreading adds a 10-20% additional boost.

Comment: thanks for running these tests. I believe that a big part of the time was in compiler output. While parallel building certainly contributed a lot, I estimate that at least 30 minutes of compile time was induced just because of the verbose logging output, in my case.

Comment: @hellofunk: Aside from being surprised that clang generates so much output (as zaphoyd verified), I'd suggest you set a lower line buffer size for your terminal. I don't think you will ever really *need* half a million lines of history, and it seems to significantly slow you down.

Comment: @DevSolar good point, that was likely a big part of the problem for me. it was just an emacs shell buffer, which keeps _everything_

Comment: `-j 8` decreased build time from 25min to 5min on Windows, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I guess you are not using parallel build option -jN (where N number of processes, could be little higher than number of cores on your machine). Also 3 min sound like single configuration on machine with sdd or ram disk, and 5 hours like all configuration with single process and slow HDD.

Comment: I didn't specify any options, just used the Boost default as provided in that link, so I guess I am not building in parallel. Would I really see an increase of at least 10x in build time by going parallel (as suggested in one of the comments to my question)?

Comment: @hellofunk: Use `./b2 -jn` with `n` equal the number of cores you have. You will see a reduction of build time of roundabout `x/n` (as should be expected). For comparison, I just did a `time ./b2 -j12` on my dev workstation (dual hexacore Xeon @ 3.3 GHz), and came up with 2:05 min real time, 22:54 min user time.

Comment: Your 22:54 of user time is still a far cry from my 300 minutes. Also, my build output (the logs that ./b2 creates) was over half a million lines according to the emacs shell buffer. Is that also normal? Perhaps all that logging was slowing things down (though not sure it is possible to disable that logging anyway).

Comment: If you have 8 Core CPU, enough memory, and disk could keep up you could get at least 8 times speedup with -j10. Also you could consider what do you need: debug/release/both, static/shared/both - single variant is much faster than all varaints

Comment: @hellofunk: It might be that your Mac defaults differ from mine (Linux). Perhaps you're building multiple variants, as ISanych hinted at. As for the logging, I get 2131 lines, and as long as it's going to terminal (as opposed to disk) it shouldn't be an issue. There's a *lot* of read/write traffic going on anyway. So... I'm not sure why your build is so slow.

Comment: @DevSolar - You will see some improvement by specifying more than the number of cores -- assuming the cores are dual cores (which they are on a 2012 MacBook Pro).

Comment: I've updated my question the great results from your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: @DavidHammen: I say "cores" in the meaning of "cores" - 2 for dual core cpus, 4 for quad-core cpus etc.

Answer (score 0):

Most boost packages are header-only. If you only need those then the installation is just copying files. Based on how many compiled packages you are doing the time may differ by several orders of magnitude. Plus yes, parallel compilation, different machine (Raspberry Pi vs 32 CPU IvyBridge Blade), etc. Plus building from and into `/dev/shm` can get you significant speedup.

Comment: How does the build directory itself affect the speed?

Comment: `/dev/shm` is backed by memory (i.e. a ram disk) rather than slower SSD or HDD.

Comment: To be fair to the OP, a lot of those un-built libs are pretty core functionalities for using Boost in the first place.